# react-native flatlist which has extraData props can`t re-render

Tags: react-native

this is offical example,I write it to my project.
however, there is a problem:flatlist item can`t re-render when state Changed.

this is my code;

```
_renderItem = ((item) => (
    <SelectListItem
        id = { item.item.id }
        onPressItem = { this._onPressItem }
        selected = { this.state.selected.get(item.id) }
        title = { item.item.title }
        />
    )
);

render(){
    return(
            <FlatList
                data = {this._dataArray}
                extraData = { this.state }
                keyExtractor = {this._keyExtractor}
                renderItem = { this._renderItem }
            />
    );
}
```

Comment: I think you problem is `extraData = { this.state }` would be `extraData = { this.state.dataSource }` or something like that ? can you provide more code example ? like your constructor or the state complete.

Comment: state code is  'this.state = {selected:(new Map():Map<String,Boolean>)}'
setState code is  this.setState((state)=>{
           const selected = new Map(state.selected);
           selected.set(id,!selected.get(id));
           //this.state.selected = selected;

           return {selected};
       });

Comment: state code : `this.state = {selected:(new Map():Map<String,Boolean>)};` and `this.setState((state)=>{
           const selected = new Map(state.selected);
           selected.set(id,!selected.get(id));
           return {selected};
       });`

Comment: I check my code and found my problem is not item re-render but other questions,thanks to @Stretch0